# How to get the total data consumed to render a web page in php

Tags: php, http, http-headers

Browser console displays the size of all downloaded css,js and images in a http request in bytes.How to get this data in php?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are making external requests using HTTP (like what Inspect Element is showing) you can parse the HTTP Header or send a HEAD request instead of GET / POST to get the Content-Length header. The HTTP Head request will not return the content of the file but only the header information which can save a lot of resources if you don't care about the content of the page you are requesting. If you do want the content, just send a GET / POST request and parse the response header that is always returned.

If you are wondering how large a file is on your own server that PHP is running on, you can use [`filesize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) which will show you the file size in bytes. If the file isn't known, a `FALSE` will be returned.

```
int filesize ( string $filename )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the http servers access log file where (usually) the transferred size is written. This requires read permission for the http server process itself and can obviously only be done *after* a request has been finished. Note that this way you will be blind towards data cached by the client side or a proxy server in between client and server.

This is an example entry:

```
::1 - - [19/Feb/2014:09:45:38 +0100] "GET /test.html HTTP/1.1" 200 129 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36 SUSE/32.0.1700.102"
```

You can see the size as "129" bytes next to the return code http-200 (OK). There are packages for this (`awstats` and the like), but in your case it might be easier to just "grep through" the file. It might be non trivial though to decide what requests belong together forming a "page load".

Answer (score 0):

Your specific requirements are a little vague (on your own server, or parsing someone else's webpages?), but you get filesize from php using this function:

```
int filesize ( string $filename );
```